# Algorithm help: I need help parsing a string that contains * as a wild card in scala

Tags: string, algorithm, scala

say I have a list of strings as such:

```
List("/", "/operators", "/assets/*")
```

and a given string value of

```
"/assets/css/main.css"
```

I want to check if the given value is in the list, but when a * is present everything after assets should evaluate to true as if it was explicitly stated in the list of strings, false otherwise.

```
if(givenStringValue is in List) true else false
```

I am still pretty fresh to scala, how should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with scala per se but it looks like you can test for a trailing "*" in the listItem, strip it off, then test weather your givenStringValue begins with the remaining listItem

Comment: @jollarvia that's a good idea, I will look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically there are 2 cases. Either the value is in the List or there is some element in the List, which ends with a `*` and also is contained in the value.

A solution in scala can be:

```
def isInList(list: List[String], value: String) = 
  list.exists(s => s == value || (s.last == '*' && value.startsWith(s.init)))
```

Here `s.last` yields the last character of a string and `s.init` yields all characters except the last.

Tests:

```
val list = List("/", "/operators", "/assets/*")
println(isInList(list, "/assets/css/main.css")) //true
println(isInList(list, "/assets/////////"))     //true
println(isInList(list, "/operators"))           //true
println(isInList(list, "/operators/"))          //false
println(isInList(list, "/something"))           //false
```

Credit goes also to **Rex Kerr**, who posted the exact same solution in the same second ;).

Comment: It's not widely known that @rex-kerr is actually IBM's Watson.

Comment: However, you may not have intended to match `"/assets/"` with the star matching the empty string or null input.

Comment: @som-snytt Sorry, can you explain it further? I'm not sure what you are saying.

Comment: I just mean `isInList(list, "/assets/") == true`. If you're checking access, you'd allow access one level higher than I understand "/assets/*" to mean, e.g., you could list the dir.